# Post Feature Image is not available for social sharing when using it as DIV background

Tags: wordpress

I am using this code

```
<div class="projectimg"  style="background-image: url('<?php echo $thumb['0'];?>')">
```

for setting up the Post Featured image for background of the DIV.

The problem is when I am trying to share the post in social platforms, e.g. Facebook, it allows to select any image from our entire post, but does not show the featured image in it.

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: look for meta tags which used by social platforms and then you will find the problem and you may fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This is because Facebook doesn't recognize background images as actual media attachments that can be used in social sharing. Your best bet is to add a line like the following to the `<head>` tag:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="<?= $thumb['0']; ?>" />
```

Comment: It won't show that image at all, it just tells Facebook "Hey, this is the image I'd like to use when this URL is shared. I suggest giving the [FB Sharing Docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters) a read.

Comment: right now it showing me content="" then what supposed to be code error?

Comment: The `$thumb` isn't defined when you put that code in, and you'll have to do something like `<meta property="og:image" content="<?= get_the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" />` instead.